# How to remote into google colabs

Tags: google-colaboratory, remote-access

I was trying to remote into google colabs. I thought that you could go through the chrome remote desktop app (It does not have to be this) but I am not sure how to set it up. If anyone knows how to set this up with an operating system like windows, please can you explain how it works and how to set it up.

Another thing which I tried was using the inbuilt app 'remote desktop' which would be better but I do not know how.

Comment: What do you mean by remote into colab ? Do you want to access the Google Colab server over ssh from your PC ?

Comment: I mean by 'remote in' is use google colab as a server which is hosting a virtual computer, which then can be connect by a computer.

Comment: Google Colab servers are behind NAT and you cannot directly remote into it using its public ip address. You need to use some tunneling like ngrok. Set it up and you will be good to go